Solve the Exact Differential Equation
\begin{equation}
(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2})dx+(ye^y+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2})dy=0
\end{equation}
The above differential equation is exact. According to the text book I'm using the formula to solve this differential equation is the following:
\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\int_{x_o}^{x}M(x,y)dx+\int_{y_o}^{y}N(x_o,y)dy=c
\end{equation}
In my lecture notes the solution is the following
\begin{equation}
ln(x)-\frac{1}{x}-arctan(\frac{x}{y})+ye^y-ey=C
\end{equation}
When trying to solve assuming $x_o$ be 1 and $y_o$ be 0 I have a remaining arctan function. If I had to guess it would be due to my point $x_o$ and $y_o$, and that it doesn
t create a simply connected region.

You don't need to use a certain value of $x_0$ and $y_0$ - just find some antiderivative.

The correct formula to solve the differential equation is
$$
f(x,y)=\int_{x_0}^xM(x',y)\,dx'+\int_{y_0}^yN(x_0,y')\,dy'=C. \tag{1}
$$
Proof. Using Leibniz integral rule in $(1)$, we obtain
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=M(x,y) \tag{2}
$$
and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}&=\int_{x_0}^x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}M(x',y)\,dx'+N(x_0,y) \\
&=\int_{x_0}^x\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}N(x',y)\,dx'+N(x_0,y) \\
&=N(x,y)-N(x_0,y)+N(x_0,y)=N(x,y).\quad\square \phantom{\int}  \tag{3}
\end{align}
Now, let's apply $(1)$ to the given ODE:
\begin{align}
\int_{x_0}^xM(x',y)\,dx'&=\int_{x_0}^x\left(\frac{1}{x'}+\frac{1}{(x')^2}-\frac{y}{(x')^2+y^2}\right)dx' \\
&=\ln|x|-\frac{1}{x}-\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)
-\ln|x_0|+\frac{1}{x_0}+\arctan\left(\frac{x_0}{y}\right), \tag{4} \\
\int_{y_0}^yN(x_0,y')\,dy'&=\int_{y_0}^y\left(y'e^{y'}+\frac{x_0}{x_0^2+(y')^2}\right)dy' \\
&=(y-1)e^y+\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x_0}\right)-(y_0-1)e^{y_0}-\arctan\left(\frac{y_0}{x_0}\right). \tag{5}
\end{align}
Substituting $(4)$ and $(5)$ in $(1)$, we get
\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=\ln|x|-\frac{1}{x}-\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+(y-1)e^y \\
&\phantom{=}+\arctan\left(\frac{x_0}{y}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x_0}\right)+g(x_0,y_0)=C. \tag{6}
\end{align}
Since $g(x_0,y_0)$ is a constant, and
$$
\arctan\left(\frac{x_0}{y}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x_0}\right)
=\frac{\pi}{2}, \tag{7}
$$
we can rewrite the solution to the ODE as
$$
\ln|x|-\frac{1}{x}-\arctan\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+(y-1)e^y=C', \tag{8}
$$
where $C'$ is a new constant.

Thank you very much. I’m was not familiar with the addition of these arctans being pi over 2. I assume this is provable by definition.

There are some proofs here.
